# ComboBox problems

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having a really weird issue with the comboBox in C# Visual Studio.

I have this code

```
private void cmbType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(cmbType.Text == "tiger")
        {
            chk1.IsChecked = true;
        }
    }
```

If I select tiger nothing happens but when I select the one below it which is "bears".. It checks the box

Comment: Is there any white space in `tiger`?

Comment: Is the tiger box checked when you change to bears?

Comment: There are no white spaces. and no.. When I select Tiger nothing happens.. When I switch to bears the checkbox gets checked. @AlfieGoodacre

Comment: @Kevin Do you have anything that is supposed to check it when you select bears?

Comment: check for case-sensitive: Tiger <=> tiger

Comment: No, the only thing that the code says about bears is adding it to a comboBox item... Other then that. 0 code for bears at all.

Comment: @Kevin the most likely thing in that case, is that the comboBox text changes ***after*** the selected index, meaning that the first time the index changes it is `""` and the second time it changes it will be `tigers` even though it was your first selection

Comment: @MiguelRodriguez No case sensitive issues

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre How do I fix this then? I need it to check the box when I select tiger not after when I switch to bears

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on your if statement and see what the value of `cmbType.Text` is when you select `tiger`?

Comment: @DrewKennedy I'm fairly new to VS, How do I get the value after I insert the break?

Comment: Set the breakpoint and run in debug mode. When the breakpoint hits, just hover over `Text`. It will tell you the value.

Comment: Check that you subscribe your method cmbType_SelectedIndexChanged to the right event and only one. The method  name by itself does not guarantee it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var comboBoxItem = e.AddedItems[0] as ComboBoxItem;
    if (comboBoxItem == null) return;
    var content = comboBoxItem.Content as string;
    if (content != null && content.Equals("tiger"))
    {
        cbAnimal.IsChecked = true;
    }
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void cmbType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if((string) cmbType.SelectedItem == "tiger")
    {
        chk1.IsChecked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: if I use that... I get this error `Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem' to type 'System.String'.`

Comment: @Kevin how have you added items to your combobox?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the comboBox items based on the index, as **the text changes after the selected index**

```
private void cmbType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(cmbType.SelectedText.ToString() == "tiger")
    {
        chk1.IsChecked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I add that, nothing happens.. Checkbox does not go for tiger or bears

Comment: @Kevin sorry, try now

Answer (score 0):

```
private void cmbType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(cmbType.SelectedValue.ToString() == "tiger")
    {
        chk1.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I add that nothing happens. Checkbox is NOT being checked.

Comment: But wait... there is no such property as IsChecked. You should use `chk1.Checked = true;`

Comment: Incorrect, I have a property IsChecked, Checked returns an error.

Comment: strange. Ok, I'm glad you found an answer, but this is pretty confusing. What .net version are you using? In fact, can you provide code used to fill in the combobox?